# change static navbar to fixed on scroll when bottom of hero section is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make the static positioned navigation bar become fixed when the end of specific section is reached?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zva77e73/46/)

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
    var navbar = $(".static-navbar");
    navbar.addClass("fixed-navbar");
})
```

Im trying to make the navigation bar become fixed as soon as "red section" is reached.
With this jQuery code above, I managed to get it fixed as soon as the scroll event is fired, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I added the slideDown feature, as asked in comments...
And it is looking great!

Two things to say about this add:

1. `.slideDown()` is intended to animate a hidden element.
   So in your case, you have to hide it first.
2. Then, a "flag" is needed to avoid it being animated too many times...
   The `scroll` event is firing like an AK47!
   ;)
3. About the `slideUp()`, you have to wait the end of the animation to remove the class making it fixed, then ensure it isn't hidden. So you do this in the `slideUp()` callback.

---

I guess you want something like in this snippet.

You just have to compare how many pixels were scrolled, using `.scrollTop()` to the `.fullscreen` `height` value.

Then it is easy to set your navigation bar as fixed or static.

```js
// Navigation state "flag"
var isFixed=false;

$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  var navbar = $(".static-navbar");
  var heroSectionHeight=$(".fullscreen").height();

  // Set fixed
  if( $(window).scrollTop()>=heroSectionHeight && !isFixed ){
    isFixed=true;
    navbar.hide().addClass("fixed-navbar").slideDown(600);
  }

  // Set static
  if( $(window).scrollTop()<heroSectionHeight && isFixed ){
    isFixed=false;
    navbar.slideUp(600,function(){
      navbar.removeClass("fixed-navbar").show();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.static-navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
.fixed-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="fullscreen">
  <nav class="static-navbar">
    Static Navbar
  </nav>
  <div style="padding-top: 280px;">HERO SECTION</div>
</div>

<div class="fullscreen bg-red" style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
  <div style="padding-top: 280px;">RED SECTION</div>
</div>
```

***This snippet is better seen in full page mode***
*(Otherwise, the height is too small and it flickers)*

Comment: Hey, It works perfect, but how do I  make the navbar slide down/up, I tried navbar.addClass("fixed-navbar").slideDown(2000); but it wont work