# Sticky navigation bar won't float to center after I tried to fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a sticky navigation bar but every time I pull it down it won't stay floated to center and it looks really bad.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a href="#Home" class="slide_section">Home</a>
  <a href="#About" class="slide_section">About</a>
  <a href="#">Other</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;

  jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
  jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
      jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      Query("nav").removeClass("fixed");
    }
  });
});
```

Same code in [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/LwgSs2qd)

I would like your feedback soon please thank you!

Comment: So you just want to have a fixed navigation on scroll more than nav height ? What the use of the wrapping `div` ?

Comment: If you do that it will not jump down

Comment: All I need is that when I scroll down, it will stay center. (float in CSS)

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43302479/2159528